# different window.width in chrome and native android browser

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome, mobile

I just realized my website looks different in Chrome, as it looks in the native Android browser. I am using my Galaxy S3 to test. I am using Bootstrap with the mobile navigation (navigation changes to the nav-symbol when the window-width is less than 768). on Chrome i have the symbol, then i saw that i have the normal navigation in the Android browser.

To test i call $(window).width(). Chrome says 360px in portrait and 640px in landscape. These are the normal resolutions from the S3. When i call this in the native browser it says 444px in portrait and 790px in landscape. Everything is smaller than in Chrome.. and I don't get the mobile navigation on landscape (because this would happen when width<767... but here the browser says it's 790)

Does anyone know whats going on here?? Thanks for your time and help :) Greetings, gertnaster